# Bash vulnerability CVE-2014-6271 (Shellshock) fix on Debian 6.0 (Squeeze)

Tags: bash, vulnerability

I upgraded my old [Debian 6.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian#Release_timeline) (Squeeze) server, but still the vulnerability seems to be there:

```
$ env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c 'echo hello'
vulnerable
hello
```

How do I upgrade Bash to a newer version on Debian 6.0 (Squeeze)?

Comment: did you start a new bash shell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get updates on older releases you will probably need to add the Debian 6.0 (Squeeze) LTS repository to your `sources.list`.

To add this repository, edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and add the following line to the end of the file.

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian squeeze-lts main non-free contrib
```

Then run:

```
apt-get update
```

You should see some new sources in the list of repositories now as the update is running. Now just:

```
apt-get install --only-upgrade bash
```

Here is a listing of my `sources.list` file from a Squeeze server I just upgraded:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main

deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main

# squeeze-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main

# Other - Adding the lsb source for security updates
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ squeeze-lts main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian/ squeeze-lts main contrib non-free
```

Comment: But I am on squeeze already

Comment: OK, when I do this (with wheezy instead of squeeze), I get `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Breaks: gcc-4.4 (< 4.4.6-4) but 4.4.5-8 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
`

Comment: and if I also upgrade gcc, I get a lot of suggestions: https://gist.github.com/rubo77/3d18256eb1622deef41a

Comment: Nah just add that line to your sources.list, i just updated a squeeze server just now with that entry in my sources.list file and then upgraded bash with no problems. I don't think that the squeeze-lts is in the file by default.

Comment: Ah I see, the **LTS** is new, I thought your answer was about older releases in the first place. Does this also solve CVE-2014-7169 by now?

Comment: Nope. Here is a test script that I have been running to check for both: https://gist.github.com/KalenAnson/231db4b468fc53a5ae7d

Comment: You have to do some more after adding the LTS source: https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Using#Using_Debian_squeeze_.286.0.29_LTS

Comment: the script you were using to test, seems to show always positive, see the issue in this alternative test: https://github.com/hannob/bashcheck/issues/6#issuecomment-57081774

Answer (score 2):

> source: [serverfault - Can not update bash on Debian Squeeze](https://serverfault.com/a/631386/128892)

You must use the `squeeze-lts` repository in order to continue receiving updates to Debian Squeeze

To add this repository, edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and add the line

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian squeeze-lts main non-free contrib
```

(you can remove `non-free` and `contrib` if desired)

To update only bash, after running `apt-get update` use `apt-get install bash` to install just bash, instead of a complete upgrade.